# How to configure Tmux so that windows monitored for activity and/or silent are marked in the status bar?

Tags: tmux

In the status bar of Tmux, the last window is marked with `-`, a window which is monitored for activity and has had an activity is marked with `#`, analog for inactivity with `~`. But I would like to know which windows are currently monitored, ideally in the status bar marked with `(#).

E.g. for the second window being monitored for activity: `0*:vim   1(#):mutt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 3.0a upwards of tmux you can set the window list format:

```
set-option -g window-status-format "#I#{?monitor-activity,(,}#{?window_flags,#{window_flags}, }#{?monitor-activity,),}:#W"
set-option -g window-status-current-format "#I#{?monitor-activity,(,}#{?window_flags,#{window_flags}, }#{?monitor-activity,),}:#W"
```

The expression form `#{var,if-true,if-false}` is extensively used to select between two values depending on whether a variable setting is on or off (or empty or not).